# Android app cannot be downloaded from play store onto tablets

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet, google-play

I have an alpha prototype of my app up on the Play Store.  For some reason, users with tablets cannot download the app – they get the message "Your device isn't compatible with this version."  I haven't had a chance to test multiple tablets, but I know this is a definitely an issue with the Nexus 7.

If I look up the device compatible through the developer's console, I see that tablets such as the Nexus 7 are listed as compatible (and no devices are listed as excluded).

I have also ensured that the tablets that cannot download the app have the latest operating system and thus should not be incompatible because of OS incompatibility.

**Does anyone know what might be the issue preventing tablets from downloading my app?**

I've included my manifest in case that's helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.activities"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/test_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SampleTheme.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As a side question, I'm interested in learning how to see whether a device is compatible with your app **before** you upload a new APK to the play store.  I never had an issue testing the app directly on the device, so I was surprised to find it is listed as incompatible on the play store.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's because of `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />` (assuming that Nexus 7 doesn't have autofocus). You can add the `android:required="false"` so the app will be available to devices that don't have autofocus too.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what might be the issue preventing tablets from downloading my app?

[`RECORD_AUDIO` requires that the device have a microphone](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions), and not all tablets will have a microphone.

Also, please remove `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CACHE" />`, since there is no such permission in Android.

Comment: I will add that the microphone isn't required.  And I'll remove the cache suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As described in the official [Tablet App Quality guide](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#hardware-requirements):

> In your app manifest, locate any [`<uses-feature>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) elements. In particular, look for hardware features that might not be available on some tablets, such as:
>
> - android.hardware.telephony
> - android.hardware.camera (refers to back camera), or
> - android.hardware.camera.front

So, you have to replace these 2 lines:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

by this one:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

& of course handle the case when the Camera feature doesn't exist in the device by this check:

```
if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 0){
    // device has camera, it is safe to use it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to this, but I do know that Play determines the list of supported devices by THESE numbers:

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

They should literally be as low as possible in order for your code to work.  The lower the number, the longer the compatibility list.

After that, the list of required permissions make a big difference.  Because some devices don't have those features that are required.  So you have to crossreference that list as well.

Comment: The odd thing is that on the play store, it says that there are no devices that aren't supported, even with the current minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersions I've specified!